# Call teradata macro having multiple select queries from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, macros, teradata, dblink

I am trying to call macros defined in teradata from a plsql procedure, by searching through various blogs online I was able to devise below process to call and get values from all the macros which only contain a single select query, but if I use the same technique to get values from a macro which might have more than 1 query in it then it fetches results of first query only.

Macro (single query) -

```
replace macro a_macro1 (arg1 (char(9)), arg2 (char(8)), arg3 (char(8))) as 
(select ret1 (char(5)), ret2 (char(3)) 
 from table1 where arg1 = :arg1 and arg2 = :arg2 and arg3 = :arg3;);
```

Macro (multiple query) -

```
replace macro a_macro2 (arg1 (char(9)), arg2 (char(5)), arg3 (char(8)), arg4 
 (char(8))) as (
 select ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4, ret5, ret6, ret7  
 from table1 where table1.arg1 = :arg1 and table1.arg2 = :arg2 
 and table1.arg3 = :arg3 and table1.arg4 = :arg4;

 select ret1, ret2 from table2 where ret2 = 'm' and 
   table2.arg1 = :arg1 
 and table2.arg3 = :arg3 and table2.arg4 = :arg4;

  select ret1, ret2 from table3 where ret2 in ('a','z') 
   and table3.arg1 = :arg1 
  and table3.arg2 = :arg2 and table3.arg3 = :arg3 and table3.arg4 = 
   :arg4;

  select ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4, ret5, ret6, ret7, ret8
   from table4 where arg1 = :arg1 and arg2 = :arg2 and arg3 = :arg3 
   and arg4 = :arg4;);
```

PLSQL method used -

```
c := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@TERA_DBLINK;
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@TERA_DBLINK(c, 'EXEC a_macro1(?,?,?)');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,1,'val1');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,2,'val2');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,3,'val3');
num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@TERA_DBLINK(c);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num_rows || ' Rows fetched');


LOOP
    num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@TERA_DBLINK(c);
    EXIT WHEN num_rows = 0;
    i := 1;
    loop 
        BEGIN
        exit when i = 99;
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@TERA_DBLINK(c, i, val1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(val1);
        i := i+1;
        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
            i:=99;
            END;
        END;
    end loop;
END LOOP;  

DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@TERA_DBLINK(c);
```

This method works fine for getting values from the first macro. How do I change it so that it works for second macro as well?

Also, is there a way of getting column names as well?

```
GET_VALUE
```

fetches only values, not the column names.

Edit 1 - 
Here is my code for calling second macro -

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
num_rows INTEGER;
c INTEGER;
i INTEGER;
val1  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
c := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@TERA_DBLINK;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor opened');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@TERA_DBLINK(c, 'EXEC a_macro2 (?,?,?,?)');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('command set for parse');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,1,'123456789');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('first variable bound');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,2,'00001');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('second variable bound');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,3,'20161215');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('third variable bound');
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@TERA_DBLINK(c,4,'15462250');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('fourth variable bound');
num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@TERA_DBLINK(c);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num_rows || ' Rows fetched');

LOOP
    num_rows := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@TERA_DBLINK(c);
    EXIT WHEN num_rows = 0;
    i := 1;
    loop 
        BEGIN
        exit when i = 99;
        DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@TERA_DBLINK(c, i, val1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(val1);
        i := i+1;
        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
            i:=99;
            END;
        END;
    end loop;
END LOOP;  

DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@TERA_DBLINK(c);
END;
/
```

Output -

```
 Cursor opened
 command set for parse
 first variable bound
 second variable bound
 third variable bound
 fourth variable bound
 1 Rows fetched
 ABCDEF02AB8
 ABCDEF02ABC
 1234
 T1F
 1F
 A
 Y
```

Only 7 values are returned, which are from the first query of second macro.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work for next macros, just make changes at this step:

```
DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@TERA_DBLINK(c, 'EXEC a_macro2(?,?,?,?,?)');
```

Dont forget to add bind varaibles as number of arguments passed.

Comment: I did try doing this, and this only returns the output from first select query, not the subsequent ones.

Comment: Am not sure how teradata macro works but you can see my answer where am passing 5times `?` to macro. I saw that when your macro1 has 3 arguments you passed 4times `?`.Now since your macro2 has 4 arguments, you must pass 5times `?` .

Comment: no, sorry, that was a typo. i am passing ? 3 times in macro1, and 4 times in macro 2